# Phonegap APK supports only 4 Screen Layouts

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

When I upload my APK to the Google Play Store, it says it only supports the following Screen Layouts (small, normal, large, xlarge) and hence I can't even test it on my own phone.

I don't believe I have any related config which would override sensible defaults, so what should I have?

Whole config.xml:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.xxx.xxx" version="2.0.2" defaultlocale="en-GB" android-versionCode="">
<name>xxx</name>
<description>xxx</description>
<author href="http://www.xxx.xxx/" email="info@xxx.xxx">xxx Ltd</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<platform name="ios|android|winphone" />

<!-- Preferences -->
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="True" />
<preference name="ShowTitle" value="False" />
<preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="True" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#104b7d" />
<!--<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="blackopaque" />-->
<platform name="ios">
<preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="True" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
</platform>
<platform name="android">
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
</platform>

<!-- Plugins -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="0.8.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="0.8.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="3.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid" spec="1.3.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.1" />

<!-- Icons -->
<icon src="icon.png" />
<platform name="android">
<icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
<icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" />
<icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" />
<!--<icon density="???" src="res/icons/android/icon-512-???dpi.png"/>-->
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<icon width="29" height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" />
<icon width="48" height="48" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon width="57" height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" />
<icon width="58" height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" />
<!--<icon width="64" height="64" src="res/icons/ios/icon-.png" />-->
<icon width="72" height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" />
<icon width="76" height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" />
<icon width="114" height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" />
<icon width="120" height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" />
<icon width="144" height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" />
<icon width="152" height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" />
<icon width="180" height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" />
<!--<icon width="320" height="320" src="res/icons/ios/icon-.png" />-->
<!--<icon width="1024" height="1024" src="res/icons/ios/icon-.png" />-->
</platform>

<!-- Splashscreen -->
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
<preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="#ffffff" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="250"/>
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<!--<splash src="splash-blank-white.png" />-->
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<platform name="android">
<splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
<splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
<splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<splash width="320" height="480" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" />
<splash width="640" height="960" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" />
<splash width="640" height="1136" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" />
<splash width="750" height="1334" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" />
<splash width="768" height="1024" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" />
<splash width="1024" height="768" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" />
<splash width="1242" height="2208" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" />
<splash width="1536" height="2048" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" />
</platform>

<!-- Security -->
<!-- This now applies only to HTTP and HTTPS on Android -->
<access origin="*" />
<!-- These are needed in Cordova 3.6 and newer for Android -->
<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="maps:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="cdvfile://*" />
<!--<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />-->
<allow-intent href="http://*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="maps:*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<!--<allow-intent href="sms:*" />-->
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<platform name="android">
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<allow-intent href="itms:*" />
<allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
</widget>
```

Please note: I'm using **PhoneGap** (Cordova) and hence am **not** editing Android XML files.

I've tried building with PhoneGap Build & with Visual Studio and have the same problem.

Comment: Have you tested it locally? You don't need to upload it to test it.

Comment: Yes, tested locally, but that skips the verification forced by the Play Store.

Comment: What screen size are you wanting it to support?

Comment: There seem to only be 4 sizes anyway. In the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html